# How many ways can $3$ pizzas with up to $4$ toppings and $3$ soft drinks be ordered?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Homer’s Pizza is advertising the following deal:

3 pizzas, up to 4 toppings each,

10 toppings to choose from,

3 soft drinks with 5 varieties to choose from,

The pizza toppings must be unique - double, triple, or quadruple toppings are not allowed. The order
of the toppings is not relevant, and 3 of the same pizza and/or 3 of the same soft drink is allowed.
What is the total number of combinations
of pizzas + soft drinks possible with this offer?

how do I show this using the intermediate formulae?

Answer (score 3):

Since the order of the toppings is not important and we cannot take the same topping twice, but we can take $0,1,2,3$ or $4$ toppings , we can choose the toppings in
$$
P={10 \choose 0}+{10 \choose 1}+{10 \choose 2}+{10 \choose 3}+{10 \choose 4}
$$
ways. There are three pizzas and we can order the same pizza twice or even three times, but the order is not important. Hence, the number of ways we can order a pizza is given by
$$
{P+3-1\choose 3}
$$
using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). Finally, there are drinks and we can order the same drink multiple times, but again the order does not matter. Using stars and bars again, we obtain
$$
{5+3-1\choose 3}.
$$
The final answer to the question is given by
$$
{P+3-1\choose 3}\cdot{5+3-1\choose 3}.
$$

Comment: Nicely presented.  And a ii-V7-I turnaround as handle, to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Build the solution up in stages:

There are $\binom{10}{0}$ pizzas with no toppings (just cheese), $\binom{10}{1}$ pizzas with one topping, etc.  Add up the proper terms to arrive at $P$, the total number of possible pizza types *with up to four toppings*.

There are $\binom{P}{3}$ different ways to order three different pizzas, $P(P-1)$ ways to order two different pizzas (two of one and one of another), and $P$ different ways to order three identical pizzas.  Add up these values to get $N$, the total number of possible pizza orders.  (In particular, we cannot assert $N = P^3$, since that would over-count pizza orders: It would treat pepperoni/pepperoni/cheese as distinct from cheese/pepperoni/pepperoni, when they are really the same order.)

Use a similar approach to obtain the number of possible drink orders.  Keep in mind that (just as in the preceding paragraph), the number of drink orders is *not* $5^3$; that over-counts them, since cola/cola/root beer should be treated the same as root beer/cola/cola.  Call $D$ the total number of drink orders.

The total number of possible overall orders is then $N \times D$.